# vue-test-utils problem with native node esm: TypeError: mount is not a function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, vue.js

I am using node's native esm implemenation to run tests.

Here's a minimal code example to reproduce. Either set "type":"module" in package.json or use .mjs extension for the test. node version >= 13.2.0 (otherwise >= 12.0 and experimental flag)

```
import {mount} from '@vue/test-utils';
// use some minimal vue component
const FooBar = import('foo-bar.vue');
const wrapper = mount(FooBar);
```

Throw the following error:

```
TypeError: mount is not a function
```

As reqested, this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mk-vue-flex-text",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My Vue component",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config build/webpack.production.js --progress --hide-modules",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node server.mjs",
    "github:master": "git push origin master",
    "test:esm": "NODE_ENV=test node test/basic.test.mjs | tap-spec",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test node test/basic.test.js | tap-spec"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "@vue/server-test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.30",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.30",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "browser-env": "^3.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "tap-spec": "^5.0.0",
    "tape": "^4.11.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^7.0.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.2",
    "vue-loader-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share you `package.json`

Comment: I added the package json

Answer (score 0):

Your FooBar `import` method isn't correct so it won't correctly mount, try this.

```
import {mount} from '@vue/test-utils';
// use some minimal vue component
import FooBar from 'foo-bar.vue';
const wrapper = mount(FooBar);
```

Comment: That's not the problem. I just used "const FooBar = import('foo-bar.vue')" in order to prevent it crashing at that point already and for feeding anything at all. You can ignore the import. My concern at the moment is that I don't get the "mount" function.

Comment: I wasn't specific, why I use  "const FooBar = import('foo-bar.vue')" instead of "import FooBar from 'foo-bar.vue'". The problem with using import ... from ... is that node will choke on it, because it doesn't recognize the extension. But, as I wrote, that's not the focus of my question.